# Как поставить курсор в конец contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно поставить курсор в конец `contenteditable` с помощью js и jq.

Answer (score 6):

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(div);
    range.collapse(false);
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae quo ratione assumenda quam deserunt, a corporis vero ipsum vitae, id libero veniam error ipsa. Magnam molestiae sapiente delectus modi odio.</div>

<button>Click me!</button>
```

UPD. С использованием jQuery

```js
 const div = $('div').get(0); // или $('div')[0];

 $('button').on('click', () => {
     const range = document.createRange();
     range.selectNodeContents(div);
     range.collapse(false);
     const sel = window.getSelection();
     sel.removeAllRanges();
     sel.addRange(range);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae quo ratione assumenda quam deserunt, a corporis vero ipsum vitae, id libero veniam error ipsa. Magnam molestiae sapiente delectus modi odio.</div>

<button>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Можно на JQ? У меня нужный div ищется JQ селекторами и при загрузке их в переменную div ничего работает

Comment: @brachkoff, дополнил в ответе